# Why doesn't my Goodman furnace make heat sometimes?

Tags: furnace

I have a 2.5 ton 2 stage Goodman furnace. It's about 5 years old. Problem is sometimes when I start it I can hear the blower start up but no heat just cold air. This is a intermittent problem sometimes it heats but most the time it doesn't. I've maintained it according to the manual, filter is clean no obstructions anywhere. I changed the batteries in the thermostat. I pretty much just turn it on and off the same way since it was installed.

Comment: What model is the furnace, and is it throwing any error codes?

Comment: The blower runs when the burner hasn't fired up? That's odd.

Comment: You could go buy a cheap mechanical thermostat to test of your thermostat is the issue. However, the blower shouldn't blow unless if senses heat, that is what one of the temp sensors in the cabinet are for, a limit sensor. If it senses it is getting to hot, it tells the blower to turn on to "cool" the system down. Could be the limit/temp sensor is going bad and the blower is coming on too soon, blowing out the burners if gas and the heat exchanger has a crack. If electric, then maybe an element issue. Are you feeling cold air blow forcefully out a vent inside the house?